# Conflict between VerifyListener and FocusListener

Tags: java, swt, listener

There is a SWT text box. I am setting a default text on it.

1. A focus listener is set so that when the focus is on the text box, the default text is deleted.
2. A verify listener is set to make sure only alphabet is entered.

However, the text is not set to empty when focus is set on the text box. What is causing this problem?

```java
final Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
text.setText("Default");
text.addFocusListener( new FocusAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void focusGained(FocusEvent event) {
           if("Default".equals(text.getText())){
           text.setText("");
           }
     }
});
text.addVerifyListener( new VerifyListener() {
     @Override
     public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
            e.doit = Verifier.isAlphabet(e.character);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Text` already has support for default text via the method [`setMessage`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html#setMessage(java.lang.String)).

So, instead of using `setText("Default")` and the focus listener you could just use `setMessage("Default");`.

The verify listener should work correctly with it.

Answer (score 0):

When your focus listener calls `text.setText("")` the verify listener is called. In this case the value of `e.character` is 0 because no character is being added. Presumably your `Verifier.isAlphabet` method is returning `false` for this and stopping the change from happening.

Your verify listener should not be testing the `character` value. You should be looking at the `VerifyEvent` `text` field which gives you the full text being changed (you may also need to look at the `start` and `end` fields).